# Tomcat deployment java error

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I'm developing a java EE web app with tomcat 7 and I'm facing a problem when I try to access to my welcome file. I get this error:

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/WEB-INF/publics/connexion.xhtml]java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.trimLeadingSlash(ResourceManager.java:364)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.getResourceInfo(ResourceManager.java:309)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.doLookup(ResourceManager.java:280)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findResource(ResourceManager.java:214)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findResource(ResourceManager.java:180)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:201)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.createResource(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:137)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.createResource(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:137)
    at org.apache.myfaces.custom.captcha.CAPTCHAResourceHandlerWrapper.createResource(CAPTCHAResourceHandlerWrapper.java:82)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.resource.UncompressedResourceHandlerWrapper.createResource(UncompressedResourceHandlerWrapper.java:107)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.resource.UncompressedResourceHandlerWrapper.createResource(UncompressedResourceHandlerWrapper.java:61)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.StylesheetRenderer.encodeEnd(StylesheetRenderer.java:97)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeBegin(HeadRenderer.java:84)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
```

I have no idea where this error comes from. Does someone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. It was in my page, I had to remove this line:

```
<h:outputStylesheet id="skin-link" library="" name=""/>
```

Works fine now.